# Error/Bug in latest ol3 version (3.9) with insertAt

Tags: openlayers

I've recently updated my ol version from 3.4 towards 3.9

I have a dragandrop layertree which basically gets the current position of the layer, removes it and inserts back in the new position using:

```
map.getLayers().insertAt(newIndex, layer);
```

this works great on V3.4 for both (bingsmap/google and for my WMS layers)

However using the same code on the latest release (3.9) I get an error for my WMS layers only (not for bings/googlemaps) as follow

```
Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed: listeners already registered
```

Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Wouldn't be better `setAt(index, layer)` since you are just changing position?

Comment: It gave me the same error. In the end i used :map.getLayers().getArray().splice(new_index, 0, layer)

Answer (score 1):

try first to remove the layer and then add it back.
Lets say you want to move it from index 6 to index 2, you should do:

```
var oldindex = 6;
var newindex = 2;
map.getLayers().removeAt(oldindex);
map.getLayers().insertAt(newIndex, layer);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I got "Assertion failed: listeners already registered" with

`var next = layers.item(index - 1);
layers.setAt(index - 1, layer);
layers.setAt(index, next);`

which I got working with:

(using ol version v3.15.1)
layers.removeAt(index);
layers.insertAt(index-1, layer);